# How can I call my data in an array on the console menu?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a program where data from a CSV file gets put into an `ArrayList`. On the user menu, the user will first press 1 to do just that, i.e., call the data from the CSV file and put it into the `ArrayList`, and then press 2 for the console to show the user what data is stored.

How can I execute option 2?

This is my menu:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        SimpleCarFactory factory = SimpleCarFactory.getInstance();
        CarStore store = new CarStore(factory);
        Car     Vauxhall = store.createCar("Vaux");
        Car Volvo = store.createCar("Vol");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);        
        int choice;
        do
        {   
            userInput();
            choice = input.nextInt();
            switch(choice)                  
            {
            case 1:      
                vauxhall.getData();
                System.out.println("Data for " + vauxhall.getName() + " car loaded successfully");
                volvo.getData();
                System.out.println("Data for " + vol.getName()  + " car loaded successfully");
                break;                      
            case 2:                     
                System.out.println(vauxhall.getData());
                System.out.println(vauxhall.getData());
            case 0:
                System.out.println("BYE");
                System.exit(0); 
                break;                      
            }
            System.out.println();                   
        }while(choice !=0);
        input.close();
    }
}
```

This is my Car class:

```
public class Car {
    static String name;
    static FileParser fileParser = null;

    ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ArrayList getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Card(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This is one of my sub-classes of Car:

```
public class Vauxhall extends Car {
    public Vauxhall(String name) {
        super(name);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    static FileParser fileParser = null;

    public ArrayList getData() {
        fileParser  = new FileParser();
        ArrayList<String> data =  fileParser.parseFile("filepath.csv");
        List<Vauxhall> VauxhallList = fileParser.populateData(data);

        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: 'put into the arraylist' part is missing. You need to store value returned from car.getDate() into List or ArrayList type variable declared in main, and then on option 2 just print it.

Comment: Your "case 2" is missing a "break" statement .

Comment: because right now when user presses option 2, it goes through the whole method getData again and reads from the csv file. Like I explained I need the data that was initially loaded in opton 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store the data arraylists, and use them in `case 2` (I also added a missing `break` statement) :

```
ArrayList vauxhallData = null;
ArrayList volvoData = null;

switch(choice)                  
            {
            case 1:      
                vauxhallData = vauxhall.getData();
                System.out.println("Data for " + vauxhall.getName() + " car loaded successfully");
                volvoData = volvo.getData();
                System.out.println("Data for " + vol.getName()  + " car loaded successfully");
                break;                      
            case 2:                     
                System.out.println(vauxhallData);
                System.out.println(volvoData);
                break;
            case 0:
                System.out.println("BYE");
                System.exit(0); 
                break;                      
            }
```